# Data Extension Import CSV Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-import

I have been having issues lately getting a CSV File to import into a Data Extension.  The initial error was that the Array Index was out of bounds - like the field counts were off.

So, I created a test Data Extension with a Single Field in it.  I created a CSV file with a single column and Single Row (after the header row).  The file looks something like this

LeadStatus
Old

The file should be imported into the DataExtension that has LeadStatus as a Field as a Text 100.  Every time it is imported I get an Error on Line #2 - Invalid Field Lead Status | bad value :Old

Any ideas?

Comment: If you create another column, setting it as a primary key, do you still get the error?

Comment: In addition to the comment of Harley, did you tick the option of "Skip rows with bad data" while importing?

Comment: The file should look like `LeadStatus, CRLF Old` with CRLF meaning Carriage Return Line Feed. It would be better if you paste the csv file in its raw status (like in a text editor). And always use UTF8, if you are not using it imports will most likely crash